# Excel Userform to search in textbox and filter in a listbox

Tags: excel, vba, search, listbox, userform

Hello I am looking for help, I have one textbox and one listbox in an Excel Userform, it works flawlessly except for one small Detail: as soon as the results appear in the listbox they represent the search within all columns. The first column, however is hidden when I type in the textbox, how can I make sure the column remains visible during search? 
Thanks in advance

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

With Sheets("Sheet1")

lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim arr(1 To lr - 1)
ReDim sn(1 To lr - 1, 1 To 13)
For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    arr(i) = .Range("A" & i + 2) & " " & .Range("B" & i + 2) & " " & .Range("C" & i + 2) & " " & .Range("D" & i + 2) & " " & .Range("E" & i + 2) & " " & .Range("F" & i + 2)
    If InStr(1, arr(i), TextBox1) > 0 Then
        j = j + 1
        For X = 2 To 8
            sn(j, X - 1) = .Cells(i + 2, X)
        Next
    End If
Next
ListBox1.List = sn

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Look at my approach here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54529352/1521579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consistent Array Approach**

Your original code shows a mixture of *array* and *range* loops when creating a filtered listbox list. In order to be more consistent here by looping through arrays only *) , you could refine your code as follows (e.g. using the same match check via `Instr`):

**Userform Event procedure `TextBox1_Change()`**

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
  Const STARTROW = 3
  Dim i&, iCnt&, r&, c&                                                       ' array counters for "rows" and "columns"
  Dim sn, tmp                                                                 ' variant 2-dim 1-based arrays
  With Sheets("Sheet1")
      iCnt = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - STARTROW + 1            ' items counter
      ReDim sn(1 To iCnt, 1 To 13)                                            ' provide for filtered data array
      For i = 1 To iCnt
         'assign current data row to 2-dim 1-based temporary array
          tmp = .Range("A" & (i + 2) & ":F" & (i + 2))                        ' current data row (c.f. OP)
         'compare search string with concatenated data string from current row
          If InStr(1, concat(tmp), TextBox1.Text) > 0 Then                    ' check occurrence e.g. via Instr
              r = r + 1                                                       ' new rows counter
              For c = 1 To UBound(tmp, 2)                                     ' col counter
                  sn(r, c) = tmp(1, c)                                        ' collect found row data
              Next
          End If
      Next
      ListBox1.List = sn                                                      ' assign array to .List property
  End With

End Sub
```

**Helper function `concat()` called by above event procedure**

```
Private Function concat(ByVal arr, Optional ByVal delim$ = " ") As String
' Purpose: build string from 2-dim array row, delimited by 2nd argument
' Note:    concatenation via JOIN needs a "flat" 1-dim array via double transposition
  concat = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(arr)), delim)
End Function
```

**Notes**

*) *Looping through a range by VBA is always time consuming, so do this with arrays instead.*

You might be also interested in the following solution demonstrating the use of the listbox [Column property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204164/listbox-error-could-not-set-the-list-property-invalid-property-value/54206396#54206396). By playing around this could help you to remove the superfluous blank rows in the listbox.

Comment: Hello T.M. Thanks for your time to answer my question, the code you provided works flawlessly, it solved my problem I have learned on my own a few things here and there about VBA codes but understanding and putting it together on my own is out of my tiny brain capabilities :) so thanks to websites like stackoverflow and to contributors like yourself I am able to achieve my userforms the way I like them to be. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. - Feel free to ask if you don't understand the special construction of a code line and found no easy assistance in the help reference or other SO sites.

Comment: Hello I am now using the search option with the code provided by T.M. it is working wonderful just how I needed it to work, I just have one more question: is it possible to modify the code to find cell value regardless if they are uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: It's trivial (always see help first :-): Just add the Argument `vbTextCompare` or `1` to the `Instr` function as follows: `If InStr(1, concat(tmp), TextBox1.Text, vbTextCompare) > 0`.  By default values get searched via `vbBinaryCompare` (= `0`) distinguishing between lower and upper case when this parameter isn't indicated explicitly as in OP.

Comment: Got it, Thank you T.M. Enjoy the weekend.